# Phy transceivers query

Tags: transceiver

- Are phy transceivers like Ethernet phy, Wlan phy and USB phy transceivers digital or analog in nature?

I referred to datasheets but it just shows transmitter and receiver as a block diagram, hence the query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Ethernet, Wlan and USB standards you mean?

Answer (score 3):

When you get to this level the distinction between digital and analog is blurred. They are digital in the sense that they deal with binary data values but they are analog in the sense that the circuits are designed to work in situations where the inductance, capacitance, and resistance of the interconnects become relevant.

Comment: Exactly. I'd definitely go with "they're both, as they transform digital information to analog signals, and vice versa".

Comment: My view is that at the physical layer (at any frequency) the signal is analog.